# How to print variable length lists as columns in python?

Tags: python, list, multiple-columns

I need a way to print several lists of varying lengths as columns next to each other tab delimited and with the empty cells remaining empty or containing some fill character (e.g "-").

The methods attempted so far have not worked for lists of varying lengths and numpy has not been working as I expected it.

To summarize:

```
listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

printed as such in a .txt file:

```
1    4    9
2    5    10
3    6    11
-    7    12
-    8    -
```

Comment: You should have a look at Python string formatting https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest). To fill the `None` spaces in the longer sequences you can use `fillvalue` (thanks @szxk):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
>>> for x in itertools.izip_longest(*listname, fillvalue="-"):
...     print '\t'.join([str(e) for e in x])
... 
1   4   9
2   5   10
3   6   11
-   7   12
-   8   -
```

Comment: One note is that izip_longest accepts a fill value as an argument, so instead you can write `itertools.izip_longest(*listname, fillvalue="-")`

Comment: @ReutSharabani Why is the conversion to string necessary for it to work? Excluding the string conversion raises an error...

Comment: If you're talking about this line: `print '\t'.join([str(e) for e in x])` it's necessary because you have a list of `int`s, and `str.join` opeartes on a list of  `str`s. Quote: *Return a string which is the concatenation of the **strings** in the iterable iterable.* https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function in this case that is more efficient for small list that `itertools.izip`

```
listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

with open('a.txt',w) as f: 
   for tup in zip(*listname) :
          f.write('\t'.join(map(str,tup))
```

A bench-marking :

```
~$ python -m timeit "import itertools;listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]];itertools.izip_longest(*listname)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]];zip(*listname)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.67 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `pandas`:

```
In [38]: listname = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

In [39]: import pandas as pd

In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame(listname, dtype=object)

In [41]: df.T
Out[41]: 
      0  1     2
0     1  4     9
1     2  5    10
2     3  6    11
3  None  7    12
4  None  8  None

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [42]: df.T.to_csv("my_file.txt", index=False, header=False, sep="\t", na_rep="-")
```